# Inequality of $k$-th moment of independent sum

Tags: probability, statistics

Recently, I am self-studying Stanford Stat 300B and encounter an exercise in the problem set, which is to prove the following:

Suppose that $X_i$ are independent mean-zero random variables with $\mathbb{E}[|X_i|^k]<\infty$, let $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ and prove that:
$$
\mathbb{E}[|S_n|^k]\leqslant C_k \mathbb{E}\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2\right)^{\frac{k}{2}}\right].
$$
I have tried to expand left hand side into terms of $X_{i_1}^{\alpha_1}\cdots X_{i_t}^{\alpha_t}$ and use the fact of independency, but in vain.

Can any body give me some hints on this problem, or provide the solution provided in https://web.stanford.edu/class/stats300b/exercise.html, since I don't have access to the solution link. Thank you very much!

Comment: Id imagine Holders inequality would be the way to go here. Holders gives you $E |S_n|^k \leq (E|S_n|^2)^{k/2}$. Perhaps try to use that the $X_i$ are centered to go from here

Comment: Just some initial thoughts…try at your own risk :)

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that it follows from the [Marcinkiewicz–Zygmund inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcinkiewicz%E2%80%93Zygmund_inequality). However, to add some value to this answer, let me break down the proof and go through some of the details$^1$.

1. Your idea of expanding $|S_n|^k$ using the Multinomial Theorem is a good idea, and is in fact used to show what is known as [Khintchine inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khintchine_inequality). It states that given i.i.d. Rademacher random variables $V_1, \dots, V_n$, some numbers $x_1, \dots, x_n\in\mathbb{R}$, and an integer $k\geq 1$,
   $$\mathbb{E}\left[\left|\sum_{i=1}^n V_i x_i\right|^{k}\right]^{1/k}\leq B_k\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\right)^{1/2},$$
   where $B_k$ is a constant depending only on $k$.

*Proof*: Assuming $k=2m$, we have (using the Multinomial Theorem and that $V_i$'s are independent)
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\left|\sum_{i=1}^n V_i x_i\right|^{2m}\right] = \sum_{\substack{\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n:\\ \alpha_1+ \dots + \alpha_n=2m}}  \binom{2m}{\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n} \prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{\alpha_i}\mathbb{E}\left[V_i^{\alpha_i}\right].$$
Now since $\mathbb{E}[V_i^p] = \mathbb{1}\{p\text{ is even}\}$, this means the non-zero terms in the sum above must have all their coefficients $\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n$ even. Hence, re-writing using $\alpha_j = 2\beta_j$ reads
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left[\left|\sum_{i=1}^n V_i x_i\right|^{2m}\right] &= \sum_{\substack{\beta_1, \dots, \beta_n:\\ \beta_1+ \dots + \beta_n=m}}  \binom{2m}{2\beta_1, \dots, 2\beta_n} \prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{2\beta_i}\\
&\leq \sum_{\substack{\beta_1, \dots, \beta_n:\\ \beta_1+ \dots + \beta_n=m}}  \frac{\binom{2m}{2\beta_1, \dots, 2\beta_n}}{\binom{m}{\beta_1, \dots, \beta_n}}\binom{m}{\beta_1, \dots, \beta_n} \prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{2\beta_i}\\
&\leq \left(\sup \frac{\binom{2m}{2\beta_1, \dots, 2\beta_n}}{\binom{m}{\beta_1, \dots, \beta_n}}\right) \sum_{\substack{\beta_1, \dots, \beta_n:\\ \beta_1+ \dots + \beta_n=m}}  \binom{m}{\beta_1, \dots, \beta_n} \prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{2\beta_i}\\
&=D_{2m} \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\right)^{m},
\end{align}
where $D_{2m} = \sup_{\substack{\beta_1, \dots, \beta_n:\\ \beta_1+ \dots + \beta_n=m}} \frac{\binom{2m}{2\beta_1, \dots, 2\beta_n}}{\binom{m}{\beta_1, \dots, \beta_n}}$. Raising each side to the power $1/(2m)$, we get the desired result,
$\mathbb{E}\left[\left|\sum_{i=1}^n V_i x_i\right|^{2m}\right]^{1/(2m)}\leq B_{2m}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\right)^{1/2}$ with $B_{2m} = D_{2m}^{1/(2m)}$. Finally, for the case where $k$ is odd, (we can write $k=2m-1)$, one should note that the LHS in Khintchine inequality is an $L_p$-norm. Since the $L_p$-norm is increasing in $p$,
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\left|\sum_{i=1}^n V_i x_i\right|^{2m-1}\right]^{1/(2m-1)} \leq \mathbb{E}\left[\left|\sum_{i=1}^n V_i x_i\right|^{2m}\right]^{1/(2m)}\leq B_{2m}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\right)^{1/2},$$
establishing the result.
$\blacksquare$

2. With Khintchine inequality proven, we can move on to the proof of Marcinkiewicz–Zygmund inequality. In this case, we have i.i.d. zero-mean random variables $X_1, \dots, X_n$ with $\mathbb{E}[|X_i|^k]<\infty$, $k\geq 1$. The statement is
   $$\mathbb{E}\left[\left|\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right|^{k}\right]\leq C_k\mathbb{E} \left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2\right)^{k/2}\right] ,$$
   where $C_k$ depends only on $k$.

*Proof:* To prove the statement, you need to play a bit with conditional expectations, use some symmetrization argument, and introduce Rademacher random variables to invoke Khintchine inequality. More formally, let $X_1^{\prime}, \dots, X_n^{\prime}$ be independent of and identically dstributed to $X_1, \dots, X_n$. With this, consider the symmetrized version of $X_i$'s, i.e., let $X_i^{\star} = X_i-X_i^{\prime}$. Moreover, let $V_1, \dots, V_n$ be i.i.d. Rademacher random variables, independent of both $X_i$'s and $X_i^{\prime}$'s.

We have
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left[\left|\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right|^{k}\right] &= \mathbb{E}\left[\left|\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^{\star}|X_1, \dots, X_n\right]\right|^{k}\right]\\
&\stackrel{\text{(Jensen's inequality)}}{\leq} \mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}\left[\left|\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^{\star}\right|^{k}|X_1, \dots, X_n\right]\right]\\
&=\mathbb{E}\left[\left|\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^{\star}\right|^{k}\right]\\
&\stackrel{\text{($X_i^{\star}$ symmetric)}}{=} \mathbb{E}\left[\left|\sum_{i=1}^n V_i X_i^{\star}\right|^{k}\right]\\
&=\mathbb{E}\left[\left|\sum_{i=1}^n V_i X_i-\sum_{i=1}^n V_i X_i^{\prime}\right|^{k}\right]\\
&\stackrel{(|x-y|^k\leq 2^{k-1}(|x|^k+|y|^k))}{\leq}  2^{k-1}\mathbb{E}\left[\left|\sum_{i=1}^n V_i X_i\right|^k+\left|\sum_{i=1}^n V_i X_i^{\prime}\right|^{k}\right]\\
&=2^k \mathbb{E}\left[\left|\sum_{i=1}^n V_i X_i\right|^k\right]\\
&=2^k \mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}\left[\left|\sum_{i=1}^n V_i X_i\right|^k|X_1, \dots, X_n\right]\right]\\
&\stackrel{\text{(Khintchine inequality)}}{\leq}  2^k B_k^k\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2\right)^{k/2}\right].
\end{align}
Hence, we have $\mathbb{E}\left[\left|\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right|^{k}\right]\leq C_k\mathbb{E} \left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2\right)^{k/2}\right]$ with $C_k = 2^k B_k^k$, as desired. $\blacksquare$

$^1:$ The proof is adapted from the material given in Section 10.3 of the book *Probability Theory: Independence, Interchangeability, Martingales (Second Edition)*, by Yuan Shih Chow and Henry Teicher.